# MongoDB: get document immediately preceding matched document

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection of documents each of which have a timestamp (let's call it 'Time').

I need to get the document immediately preceding a matched document, when ordered by 'Time'.

I know I can do this with another query per matched document, but is there any way to do it in one query?

Example:

```
{ _id: ObjectId("621e6abb0f91a6d1ba18d48f"),
  type: 'Warning',
  time: 2022-03-02T12:58:31.984Z }
{ _id: ObjectId("621e6abc0f91a6d1ba18d490"),
  type: 'Error',
  time: 2022-03-02T12:59:32.253Z }
```

So given this data I want to query for documents with type 'Error', and then also retrieve the document immediately preceding it so:

```
    { _id: ObjectId("621e6abc0f91a6d1ba18d490"),
      type: 'Error',
      time: 2022-03-02T12:59:32.253Z,
precedingLog:     { _id: ObjectId("621e6abb0f91a6d1ba18d48f"),
      type: 'Warning',
      time: 2022-03-02T12:58:31.984Z }
 }
```

Comment: How do you match a document? Like sorting by time and then equality on some field?

Comment: @Dharmaraj I've added some example data

Comment: Do the matching documents belong to a "group", and if so what is that criteria?

Comment: @prasad_ other than being in the same collection, no.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an approach you can use:

- Get all documents less than the time filter - matching document.
- Sort by time descending.
- The first document, is the the result.

Sample documents and the query:

```
{ "time" : ISODate("2022-03-02T00:00:00Z") }
{ "time" : ISODate("2022-03-01T00:00:00Z") }
{ "time" : ISODate("2022-02-21T00:00:00Z") }
{ "time" : ISODate("2022-02-28T00:00:00Z") }
{ "time" : ISODate("2022-02-09T00:00:00Z") }

matching_time = ISODate("2022-03-01T00:00:00Z")

db.collection.find({ time: { $lt: matching_time } })
             .sort({ time: -1 })
             .limit(1)
```

This returns the document with `"time" : ISODate("2022-02-28T00:00:00Z")` - the one preceding the `matching_time`.

Comment: Thanks, yes this what I'm currently doing. I wondered if there was a way to do it in one query  though

Comment: That is one query only!